# Group By combined to CASE (SQL DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

I have a database of customers with this columns (sample) :

| ID | TIMESTAMP | TYP_EVEN | NAME | COUNTRY | GENDER | NBR_CHILDREN | ADRESS | CUSTOMER_LINKED | TYP_OF_LINK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 044348547 | 2020-09-08-02.02.21.442908 | 0004 | NXXX CORINNE | FRA | 2 | 02 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044379039 | 2020-07-17-11.17.55.410843 | 0013 |  |  |  | 00 | 11 RUE XXXX XXX | 000000000 |  |
| 044379039 | 2020-07-21-16.45.53.485200 | 0004 | KXXX STEPHANE | FRA | 1 | 00 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044379039 | 2020-08-05-02.02.41.403053 | 0004 | KXXX STEPHANE | FRA | 1 | 00 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044385911 | 2019-01-31-02.03.22.455660 | 0004 | SXXX PHILIPPE | FRA | 1 | 02 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044385911 | 2020-09-18-15.46.31.387588 | 0004 | SXXX PHILIPPE | FRA | 1 | 02 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044385911 | 2020-09-30-02.01.45.310449 | 0004 | SXXX PHILIPPE | FRA | 1 | 02 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044385911 | 2020-10-01-00.06.20.341427 | 0013 |  |  |  | 00 | 19 RUE XXXX XXXX | 000000000 |  |
| 044680501 | 2021-03-10-02.02.42.979297 | 0004 | HXXX STEPHANE | FRA | 1 | 00 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044680501 | 2021-03-10-02.02.42.980069 | 0013 |  |  |  | 00 | 22 RUE XXXX XXXX | 000000000 |  |
| 044680501 | 2021-03-10-02.02.42.981083 | 0029 |  |  |  | 00 |  | 044680519 | MARIED |
| 044680519 | 2021-03-10-02.02.42.966522 | 0004 | HXXX LIDWINE | FRA | 2 | 02 |  | 000000000 |  |
| 044680519 | 2021-03-10-02.02.42.970031 | 0029 |  |  |  | 00 |  | 044680501 | MARIED |

**TYP_EVEN** : is type of event about the record for each customers ID, then **OOO4** : is about informations of the customer (NAME, COUNTRY, GENDER, Number of children), **0013** : is about the ADRESS informations and **0029** : is about link beetwen customers

I would like to have one row by ID with all informations. I proceed like this :

```
    SELECT
T1.ID,
CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0004' THEN T1.NAME END AS NAME,
CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0004' THEN T1.COUNTRY END AS COUNTRY,
CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0004' THEN T1.GENDER END AS GENDER,
CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0004' THEN T1.NBR_CHILDREN END AS NBR_CHILDREN,

CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0013' THEN T1.ADRESS END AS ADRESS,

CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0029' THEN T1.CUSTOMER_LINKED END AS CUSTOMER_LINKED,
CASE WHEN T1.TYP_EVEN = '0029' THEN T1.TYP_OF_LINK END AS TYP_OF_LINK
,T1.TIMESTAMP

FROM DB.CUSTOMERS T1

GROUP BY GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.TIMESTAMP, T1.TYP_EVEN,T1.NAME,T1.COUNTRY,T1.GENDER,T1.NBR_CHILDREN,T1.ADRESS
,T1.CUSTOMER_LINKED, T1.TYP_OF_LINK 
ORDER BY 1
```

the result should be :

| ID | NAME | COUNTRY | GENDER | NBR_CHILDREN | ADDRESS | CUSTOMER_LINKED | TYP_OF_LINK |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 044348547 | NXXX CORINNE | FRA | 2 | 02 | 11 RUE XXXX XXX | 000000000 |  |  |  |
| 044379039 | KXXX STEPHANE | FRA | 1 | 00 |  | 000000000 |  |  |  |
| 044385911 | SXXX PHILIPPE | FRA | 1 | 02 | 19 RUE XXXX XXXX | 000000000 |  |  |  |
| 044680501 | HXXX STEPHANE | FRA | 1 | 00 | 22 RUE XXXX XXXX | 044680519 | MARIED |  |  |
| 044680519 | HXXX LIDWINE | FRA | 2 | 02 |  | 044680501 | MARIED |  |  |

More information: if an ID have 2 rows with same TYP_EVEN then choose the latter one by the TIMESTAMP.

Could someone have any idea to resolve this SQL Statement ?

Comment: "it not work" doesn't tell us much, please be more explicit. Also, `GROUP BY` should be used with aggregation, use `DISTINCT` if you want unique rows. What do you want if an id has multiple TYP_EVEN values?

Comment: With DISTINCT also not work.

Comment: Like I said, simply stating something doesn't work isn't helpful

Comment: If an ID have multiple values TYP_EVEN, i want to concatenated it on one row

Comment: How? Which value do you want to see?

Comment: Ok i'm going to update my question with adding the table of the result

Comment: @HoneyBadger, please find in top the update of my question

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: That give my a result but the number of row are exactly the same, it's same result before and after the SQL statement

Comment: You need to first select the rows with the respective max date. You can use a windowed function like `DENSE_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` to easily achieve this. If you search for it you'll find many examples

Comment: @HoneyBadger, i also update my SQL code to this way but the results are not accurate

Comment: What I said about "it not work", please also apply it to "the results are not accurate"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do what you want

```
with customers (id, timestamp, typ_even, name, country, gender, nbr_children, adress, customer_linked, typ_of_link) as (
  values
  (044348547, timestamp('2020-09-08-02.02.21.442908'), 0004, 'NXXX CORINNE', 'FRA', 2, 02, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044379039, '2020-07-17-11.17.55.410843', 0013, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00, '11 RUE XXXX XXX', 000000000, NULL),
  (044379039, '2020-07-21-16.45.53.485200', 0004, 'KXXX STEPHANE', 'FRA', 1, 00, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044379039, '2020-08-05-02.02.41.403053', 0004, 'KXXX STEPHANE', 'FRA', 1, 00, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044385911, '2019-01-31-02.03.22.455660', 0004, 'SXXX PHILIPPE', 'FRA', 1, 02, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044385911, '2020-09-18-15.46.31.387588', 0004, 'SXXX PHILIPPE', 'FRA', 1, 02, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044385911, '2020-09-30-02.01.45.310449', 0004, 'SXXX PHILIPPE', 'FRA', 1, 02, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044385911, '2020-10-01-00.06.20.341427', 0013, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00, '19 RUE XXXX XXXX', 000000000, NULL),
  (044680501, '2021-03-10-02.02.42.979297', 0004, 'HXXX STEPHANE', 'FRA', 1, 00, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044680501, '2021-03-10-02.02.42.980069', 0013, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00, '22 RUE XXXX XXXX', 000000000, NULL),
  (044680501, '2021-03-10-02.02.42.981083', 0029, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00, NULL, 044680519, 'MARIED'),
  (044680519, '2021-03-10-02.02.42.966522', 0004, 'HXXX LIDWINE', 'FRA', 2, 02, NULL, 000000000, NULL),
  (044680519, '2021-03-10-02.02.42.970031', 0029, NULL, NULL, NULL, 00, NULL, 044680501, 'MARIED')
)
select ID,NAME,COUNTRY,GENDER,NBR_CHILDREN,ADRESS,CUSTOMER_LINKED,TYP_OF_LINK from (
  select
    id,
    last_value(name, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp) name,
    last_value(country, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp) country,
    last_value(gender, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp) gender,
    last_value(nbr_children, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp) nbr_children,
    last_value(adress, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp ) adress,
    last_value(customer_linked, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp ) customer_linked,
    last_value(typ_of_link, 'IGNORE NULLS') over(partition by id order by timestamp ) typ_of_link,
    rownumber() over(partition by id order by timestamp desc) seq
  from customers
) where seq = 1
order by id
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d26d135a95c26dcd3203a5dd5fd31c60), Corinne NXXX has no address

Comment: i have this error : Element syntaxique , incorrect. Elements possibles : ( + - ? . are you sure this SQL code work in DB2 database ?

Comment: @IbD It does using DB2LUW 11.1 (see fiddle), or DB2 for IBMi 7.3 (also I had to slightly modify the first line of values, and just made the edit to my answer). Which DB2 DBMS do you use ? And which version ?